# htaccess: double lang marker in url (multilanguage)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, double, lang

I have problem with htaccess. On my site I have url:

> http://domain.com/de/de/shop/kategorien/andere/angel-2-detail

instead of

> http://domain.com/de/shop/kategorien/andere/angel-2-detail

Rule below doesn't work:

> RewriteRule ^de/de/(.*)$ /de/$1 [R=301,L]

How to redirect it properly?

Comment: Should work - what error does it throw (if any)? Or, does it simply not rewrite?

Comment: There are no errors. Just doesn't work.
Maybe it should be done by RedirectMatch?

Comment: That should work for you - have you tried it yet?

Comment: It works. I have more rewrite rules and it causes problem. So I changed order of rules and its ok now. Thank you :)